# Laravel and AngularJS in Homestead

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, homestead

I want to get started with Homestead for my project. This is an existing project, and it works when using a standard WAMP stack.

I use backend and frontend as separate applications, but on the same domain, like this: 
Laravel as rest backend at url homestead.app/api/public.
AngularJS as frontend at url homestead.app/client.

I have mapped my homestead.app site to /home/vagrant/project1, where the two folders api and client are located.

When trying to access homestead.app/api/public I got the Laravel welcome page. So far so good. But when trying homestead.app/api/public/user/info, the nginx log says /home/vagrant/project1/index.php is missing. But this is wrong, since the file is located at /home/vagrant/project1/api/public/index.php.

Any advice on how to be able to use homestead for my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good scenario to use a separate subdomain for the API (api.homestead.app), or just a different domain altogether.

Check out the section "Adding additional sites" in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead):

> Once your Homestead environment is provisioned and running, you may want to add additional Nginx sites for your Laravel applications. You can run as many Laravel installations as you wish on a single Homestead environment. There are two ways to do this: First, you may simply add the sites to your Homestead.yaml file and then run homestead provision or vagrant provision.

Comment: I guess, but then I'll have to use CORS, I think. Also I was hoping to only have one domain.

Comment: Laravel apps should really be served from the public directory. That way the rest of the application is unreachable over HTTP, which is important for security. Apart from separate domains your other option would be to merge the frontend into your Laravel codebase.

Comment: That, I didn't think of. Thanks!